# Decreasing value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am learning python and I have a simple problem with my program. I have two dictionaries with a keys as a string and values connected to them. Lets say that it's a shop with fruits and prices.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Function to calculate the bill
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0

    for number in food:
        if (stock[number]>0):
            total += prices[number]
            stock[number] -= 1
    return total

print compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

If the fruit is in stock add the price to the bill and reduce the amount in the stock. If not, don't do anything.

ERROR Message:

> calling compute_bill with a list containing 1 apple, 1 pear and 1 banana resulted in 0 instead of the correct 7

I don't know why this code is not working properly.

Comment: get the return out of there. You want all items to run before the function terminates.

Comment: so is it still not working ?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis working now. One unnecessary line. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

- You return **immediately** after testing the first item, ignoring the rest of your items. `return` exits a function, the moment Python executes it.
- You decrement your stock in the wrong place, outside of the loop.

Both will need correcting:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0

    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            # this item is in stock. Add the price to the total,
            # and reduce the stock by one.
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item] -= 1
    # with the loop done, return the total sum of all items
    # that were in stock.
    return total
```

Now, instead of immediately returning `total` for the *first* item you test, you test all items. And whenever you have found an item that is in stock, you add the price for that one item to the total, and reduce the stock for that item by 1.

One final detail, the Code Academy tester calls the `compute_bill()` function *for you*. Don't call it yourself in your code, otherwise the test fails as you have changed the stock to begin with. Remove the `print compute_fill(shopping_list)` line.

Comment: Hi, Right now it telling me that I am calling the function before the stock has been reduced: "stock doesn't look quite right! Make sure to not call compute_bill since it changes the stock! It should contain: {'orange': 32, 'pear': 15, 'banana': 6, 'apple': 0}"

Comment: @Maltesse: ah, no, you are not supposed to call the function *yourself*. Remove the `print compute_bill(shopping_list)` line, the tester does this *for you*.

Comment: Thanks,. The last line was wrong when I was calling the function by passing the shopping_list. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your functions terminates prematurely because of the `return` call in your `if` statement.

They way your code is, the function will check a single item out of the basket and then exit. What you have and want to do is check **all** items, add their prices to your total and decrement their stock size according to the supply you have. To do that, your function has to be modified as follows:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0

    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item] -= 1
    return total
```

As you can see, the `else` part has been taken out as well. Since no action is taken if a requested item is out of stock or does not even exist, there is no reason for you to try and handle anything.

A final note is that the parentheses on your `if` statement are not needed in this case. This is a very simple check you are doing and trying to regulate the order of operations is redundant since the meaning is trivial.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I posted a comment on OP's question and didn't think of explaining the logic again but you are totally right. Is it better now?

Comment: *much* better now, thanks for updating. Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

`returns` ends the function and returns the value back to out of the function. If you return inside of a loop the rest of the loop will not run anymore and you will only take the first item into account.